# UIImagePickerController blurry overlayview?

Tags: iphone, ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, blur

I know that it is possible to add a transparent/translucent overlay view on a UIImagePickerController by using the drawrect method and by adjusting the alpha value of a CGRect UIColor for example. But is it possible to get a blurry effect instead of the translucent one ? I hope I am clear enough...
Thanks !

EDIT (add code)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

CGFloat toolbarSize = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 0 : 80;

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - toolbarSize;

CGFloat heightSpan = floor(height / 2 - self.cropSize.height / 2);
CGFloat widthSpan = floor(width / 2 - self.cropSize.width  / 2);

//fill outer rect
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0. blue:0. alpha:0.5] set];
UIRectFill(self.bounds);

//fill inner border
[[UIColor colorWithRed:1. green:1. blue:1. alpha:0.5] set];
UIRectFrame(CGRectMake(widthSpan - 1, heightSpan - 1, self.cropSize.width + 2, self.cropSize.height + 2));

//fill inner rect
[[UIColor clearColor] set];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(widthSpan, heightSpan, self.cropSize.width, self.cropSize.height));


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this framework to achieve a blurry view, worked really well for me

[FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)